# Gson adding backslash in String

Tags: java, gson

I am having user defined object Customer which has multiple attributes ,in one of the attributes we can have single , double quotes and backslash as well. While converting the object to string Gson library is adding backslash in it.
I am using below code to achive this but it is not working.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
JsonElement jsonString = gson.toJsonTree(triggerModel);
```

Output is

```
{
  "customerId": "1234",
  "customerName": "Loren",
  "customerAddress": [
    {
      "postalcode": "67676",
      "lane": "\"LA16767",
      "houseNumber": "2025",
      "society": "null"
    }
  ]
}
```

In lane attribute the original value was "LA16767 but it is adding one backslash character. How to write this in such a way string with single ,double quotes and backslash are handled using same line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output provided by Gson is correct because `"lane": ""LA16767"` would not have been a valid json.

From [json docs](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.

You had mentioned :

> How to write this in such a way string with single ,double quotes and backslash are handled using same line of code.

You need not do anything special to handle single ,double quotes and backslash characters. Gson will automatically escape them for you.

Any app (server, UI, etc,) who is consuming your json, will correctly parse `"\"LA16767"` as `"LA16767` going by the json conventions.