# When parse the string to JsonElement, how to avoid auto read escape character?

Tags: java, gson

I have a simple json str like below

```json
{
"foo":"\uv"
}
```

I want to use gson to parse this str to jsonElement.
eg.

```java
String input = "{\"foo\":\"\\uv\"}";
JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(input);
```

But gson throw the com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException, java.lang.NumberFormatException: \uv

It seems like when JsonReader meet the '\', it will automaticly treat it as a escape character.So, What can I do to make gson treat it as plain text instead of escape character?

Comment: Iterate through the characters in that String -- you'll see that it doesn't contain a \.

Comment: I tried your code and it works correctly without throwing any exception! You have also a minor typo in your code `parserString` must be `parseString`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo on input string it should be `String input = "{\"foo\":\"\\uv\"}";`
I have been correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do should not be possible. Forcing gson to accept `\` as plain text would be forcing it to not follow json conventions.

Also your json is not valid, correct one would be:

```
{
  "foo":"\\uv"
}
```

Check [gson adding backslash in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532879/gson-adding-backslash-in-string), it has good explanation. Using your code as example:

```
public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "{\"foo\":\"\\\\uv\"}";
    JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(input);
    System.out.println("foo value - " + element.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("foo").getAsString());
  }
}
```

This prints - `foo value - \uv`, which should be exactly the value your consumers need.